# vscode testing with pytest for dockerized Django project

Tags: django, docker, visual-studio-code, testing, pytest

i want to debug my tests in vscode for my Django project witch is set up in a docker container but the problem is it always says pytest discovery error,
sometimes it seems to not be able to import modules(for example models) inside the test file and after some configuration it seems to not find the test file itself. all the folders of my project have an **init**.py file so everything is treated as a package, by the way there is no problem importing modules in my Django project.
the odd thing is when I run pytest inside of my docker container it works fine but I want to debug the tests.
i am fairly new to this so any help would be welcome[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cKamw.png)

I enabled pytest in the .vscode/settings.json[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2qjSl.png) file as some other settings
I tried also creating a .env file with PYTHONPATH in it to my root folder cause every tutorial I found work with a virtual environment and not a docker container

Comment: Do you need Docker at all for this setup, or can you set up a normal non-Docker virtual environment and do debugging there?  [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)  If you have Python source or other configuration that's relevant to the question, please [edit] the question to include it directly in the question as plain text.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: yes I need a docker setup, it's part of a large project